# Bar code scanner APK file not works fine in LG Optimus me and LG Optimus Pro mobiles

Tags: android, apk

Bar code scanner works fine in the Samsung galaxy s551 but it is not works that good in
following mobiles samsung galaxy y,LG Optimus me and LG Optimus Pro...
Why it so?..

Comment: How did you install it from the market place or through adb? And what are the Android versions of those phones that you are saying not working your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These above mobiles are not supporting Auto focus feature in Camera. Mobile camera with Auto focus feature only able to scan bar code.